# Kivy: Controlling Video depth like a widget

Tags: kivy, video-processing, depth

At first I was thinking, is it possible to render a video in kivy to a widget (my test proves no) but then I thought about why I wanted to do that and the answer was placement control.

You can set pos and size to a video so that's no problem but what if you wanted to have four widgets set partially behind your video and four other widgets in front of it?

Just giving it a guess based on my kivy experience...  The answer might be "children."  It seems widgets, canvas and even root have the 'children' attribute and the order of the children rendered is equal to the order of the 'children' list.

Could this be true?  Could it really be that simple...just reorder the root.children?

Even if this theory is true, it won't work if you're drawing graphics from the canvas.  Canvas children always appear on top of everything else.

Any takers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I understood your question, but I think you're either looking for `children` for this structure:

```
parent
|
- 4 widgets behind
|
- video
|
- 4 widgets after
```

and (re)add the widgets to move the video between them, or...

Use [Scatter](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scatter.html) for your widgets to make it "independent" of the children position in the widget tree. What it does is basically [the same thing](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scatter.html#automatic-bring-to-front) but in the background.

An example of how that looks you can see in the [Pictures demo](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/examples/demo/pictures).